# In state-space representation, how to bring out a variable from state matrix and make it state variable

Tags: matrix, controller, linear-algebra, state-space

[image]

[image]

Above is equation for a system in State-Space representation. I can solve this and get states x_1 to x_4. Now I want to bring out **p** of the equation and make it a state variable.
[image]